# Помогите решить задачу на python уже 2 часа сижу

Tags: python, массивы, олимпиада

Игра сотри из массива
Однажды Эшмату стало скучно, и он позвонил своему брату Тошмату поиграть в игру. В игре используется массив различных значений. Правила игры следующие:

Тошмат всегда начинает игру первым.

- В каждом ходу игрок выбирает максимальный элемент из массива и удаляет максимальный элемент и все последующие элементы массива из массива. Например, если массив находится в состоянии [2, 4, 5, 3, 1], после  удаления [5, 3, 1]  в массиве останется [2,4].
  Игроки ходят по очереди.
  Игрок, который не может сделать ход (невозможно сделать ход, если массив пуст) проигрывает игру.
  Эшмат и Тошмат сыграли в игру T раз, для каждой игры выясните, кто выиграл игру.

Входные данные:
Первая строка входного файла содержит единственное целое число T(1≤T≤100). Начиная со следующей строки, первая строка из двух отдельных строк для каждой игры вводит одно целое число N(1≤N≤10^5), количество элементов массива в начале игры, а вторая строка содержит N целые числа, элементы массива в промежутке чисел [1, 10^9].

Выходные данные:
В выходном файле выведите победителя игры в отдельной строке для каждой игры!

```
Примеры
#   input.txt   output.txt
1               Eshmat
2               Toshmat
5
5 2 6 3 4
2
3 1
```

пробовал так почему почемуто застревает на while

```
a = int(input())

moves = 0
for i in range(a):
    b = []
    total = int(input())
    b.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
    while len(b) != 0:
        for i in range(b.index(max(b)),len(b)):
            b.pop(i)
        moves+=1
    if moves%2 == 0:
        print("Eshmat")
        moves = 0
    else:
        print("Toshmat")
        moves = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        for i in range(b.index(max(b)),len(b)):
            b.pop(i)
```

Когда вы удаляете i-й элемент из списка, то теперь i-м элементом станет тот, который был (i+1)-м. Т.е. этот цикл не удаляет все элементы за максимальным, а удалит несколько элементов ("через один") и выйдет за пределы массива. Вместо, удаления хвоста, проще сформулировать задачу как "оставить столько-то элементов от головы списка":

```
       b=b[ : b.index(max(b)) ]
```

Comment: но всё равно не успеет по времени. а задача решается без удаления за один проход...

Comment: `del b[b.index(max(b)):]` удаляет хвост.

Answer (score 0):

Первая ошибка в примере - первая строка лишняя.

Вторая ошибка - массив `b` оказывается списком из одного элемента - другого списка. Вот так: `[[5, 2, 6, 3, 4]]`. Поэтому ответ всегда `Toshmat`.

Третья ошибка проявляется во время удаления хвоста списка. Нельзя менять массив в цикле `for`. Это не работает, так как вы ожидаете.

После минимальных правок получится такой код. Он правильный, но не пройдёт по времени.

```
a = int(input())

moves = 0
for i in range(a):
    total = int(input())
    b = list(map(int, input().split()))
    while len(b) != 0:
        del b[b.index(max(b)):]
        moves += 1
    if moves % 2 == 0:
        print("Eshmat")
        moves = 0
    else:
        print("Toshmat")
        moves = 0
```

Вычислить количество ходов можно без изменения массива. Достаточно сосчитать сколько раз при проходе по списку обновится текущий максимум. Это число равно числу ходов в игре:

```
for i in range(int(input())):
    input()
    moves = 0
    max_so_far = 0
    for v in map(int, input().split()):
        if v > max_so_far:
            max_so_far = v
            moves += 1
    if moves % 2 == 0:
        print("Eshmat")
    else:
        print("Toshmat")
```